# Задание программного позиционирования Layout'ов

Tags: android

Есть 2 layout которые я создаю динамически(они находятся в CardView)

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    //LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparamsFile = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150);

    LinearLayout linearLayoutTextContent = new LinearLayout(ctx);     //Контейнер для текста сообщения
    linearLayoutTextContent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    linearLayoutTextContent.setLayoutParams(lparams);

    LinearLayout linearLayoutFileContent = new LinearLayout(ctx);//Контейнер для вложения
    linearLayoutFileContent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    linearLayoutFileContent.setLayoutParams(lparams);
```

Как мне сделать так чтобы `linearLayoutFileContent` находился под `linearLayoutTextContent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LinearLayout mainLayout = new LinearLayout(ctx);     //Главный Layout
linearLayoutTextContent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
linearLayoutTextContent.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

mainLayout.addView(linearLayoutTextContent);
mainLayout.addView(linearLayoutFileContent);
```

Comment: Да, вот только 2 layout'да накладываются друг на друга, а мне нужно чтобы один был под другим

Comment: @Heaven в смысле под другим? Например, вы хотите чтобы в главном `Layout` были 2 `LinearLayout` 1 сверху другой снизу? т.е. чтобы после 1, шел 2 `layout` ?

Comment: Верно, вот только при добавлении  linearLayoutTextContent.addView(linearLayoutTextContent); они накладываются друг на друга

Comment: @Heaven ну вам надо тогда добавить их в главный `Layout`, если вы всю разметку создаете программно, то создайте еще 1 `Layout`, который будет главным и добавьте туда сначала `linearLayoutTextContent`, а потом `linearLayoutFileContent`, и как вы сказали так и будет, 1 `layout` будет под другим